# Get values from xlRangeValueMSPersistXML resultant XML

Tags: xml, vba

I am trying to read the following XML from

`ActiveCell.Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueMSPersistXML)`

```
<xml xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"
 xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882"
 xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
 <x:PivotCache>
  <x:CacheIndex>1</x:CacheIndex>
  <s:Schema id="RowsetSchema">
   <s:ElementType name="row" content="eltOnly">
    <s:attribute type="Col1"/>
    <s:extends type="rs:rowbase"/>
   </s:ElementType>
   <s:AttributeType name="Col1" rs:name="Field1">
    <s:datatype dt:type="float"/>
   </s:AttributeType>
  </s:Schema>
  <rs:data>
   <z:row Col1="0.33333333333333331"/>
  </rs:data>
 </x:PivotCache>
</xml>
```

Using the following code, however, I am struggling to get the contents of

```
Dim x As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim s As String
Dim p As IXMLDOMNode

s = ActiveCell.Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueMSPersistXML)

Set x = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
x.LoadXML (s)

Set p = x.FirstChild
```

`<s:datatype dt:type="float"/>` and `<z:row Col1="0.33333333333333331"/>`  I only seem to get a return for `<x:PivotCache>`  There only seems to be one child, and looking from the locals window I can not see much else.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i tried doing it in powershell just to see how to navigate through the scheme.... Im not sure how to translate it into vba but here is the navigation

for `<s:datatype dt:type="float"/>` you can use something like

`Set p = x.xml.PivotCache.Schema.Attributetype.datatype.type`or
`Set p = x.PivotCache.Schema.Attributetype.datatype.type`

and for `<z:row Col1="0.33333333333333331"/>` you can use something like

`Set p = x.xml.PivotCache.data.row.Col1` or
`Set p = x.PivotCache.data.row.Col1`

i cant really test it but hopefully that helps...